# Should I create separate tables for each category?

Tags: c#, performance, database-design, sqlite

So, I have recently been tasked with transferring an old Flat File System Scheduling system into a SQL Database using C#.

The main issue I am finding is the fact that the tasks (See snippet below) use a List of strings (Created using GUIDs) has made me unsure of how to structure the database.

```
public class Task
{
      private string TaskID;

      private string TaskName;
      private string TaskDescription;

      private bool IsComplete;

      private DateTime EstimatedStartDate;
      private DateTime ActualStartDate;

      private DateTime EstimatedCompletionDate;
      private DateTime ActualCompletionDate;

      private string TeamLead;
      private List<string> TeamMembers = new List<string>();

      private TaskType TaskType;
      private string ParentID;
      private List<string> ChildIDs = new List<string>();
}
```

When it comes to SQL I know that using list that can only be contained in a single Cell are generally a nono.

The real question is: Should I be having this in a list where the query will only have to query the taskID or parentID to find the requested task OR to have it split into different tables for each Category in the system (This works in 4 different Categories) and then dependant on the task's type and taskID to choose the correct table it will need to query for its children.

Comment: In order to be able to understand any answer that could be given to this question, you should read up on relational database systems first. The question as is shows a severe lack of knowledge thereof.

Comment: I would probably have a table for Task and two tables linking to this via an incrementing primary key for TeamMembers and ChildIDs. Possibly also a table for TaskType if you want it normalized. Are the ChildIDs links to other tasks? In that case having the table for Children linking to the childs primary key would maby be an idea instead of using the Guid.

Comment: You need to read on how to normalize a database. In your case you will have a table *Task* and it will reference itself (parent), *Team* table, *TeamMember* table. A *Team* can have many *TeamMember* and possibly (depending on your requirement) the other way too so then you have many-to-many relationship to deal with. You get the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps if you define the problem domain more clearly, using a semi-formal syntax. Interpreting your code snippet, I think it boils down to the following.

```
A task is identified by TaskID
A task has attributes name, description etc.
A task has exactly one person, in the role "TeamLead".
A task has 0 or more persons, in the role "team member".
A task has exactly one type, selected from a collection of valid types.
A task may or may not have a relationship to another task, in the role ParentTask
A task has a relationship with 0 or more other tasks, in the relationship "childTask".
```

If this is true, you can see the relational model emerging.

In general, any relationship where you have "x..n" connections leads to a bridging table. In your case, that's "`TeamMembers`", with `TaskID` and `PersonID` as foreign keys. ChildTasks is a similar relationship.

In the case where there's "has exactly one", or "may have one", it's a foreign key. TeamLead and TaskType are examples.

There is absolutely no reason to create different tables for task type - the relational model encourages you to group similar things together, and distinguish them by data, rather than by structure.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple tables with the same structure and the same meaning is a strong antipattern: you have to modify all your queries to access the correct table (which gets especially complex if you want to summarize data from multiple categories), and you would have to modify the database structure whenever the set of possible categories changes. There is unlikely to be any measurable (let alone noticeable) performance difference.

In other words, never put *data* into the *table name*.